# Can't edit textbox

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I just inserted an ordinary textbox in an Excel sheet. Now for some reason, the text box is not selectable at all. When I hover the mouse over it, the cursor turns to a circle with a sloped line inside and I can't click the box at all. The closest thing to a solution I have found is that it has something to do with beeing in "Design Mode" however, the design button is greyed out, along with much else. Everything under the Insert tab is greyed out.

Does anyone know about this phenomenon?

Comment: What kind of text box? An insert text box or an activeX control text box or a group box form control?

Comment: Just an ordinary text box - no activeX control or such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently had a similar issue with an Excel sheet. The text boxes became unselectable, uneditable. Neither Office 2010 nor Office 2013 could open it. I figured out that my issue was somehow caused by workbook sharing, and the issue was resolved (textbox was again editable) when I went to Review on the Ribbon and clicked "Share Workbook", and then removed any users listed in the dialog box in order to disable sharing.

Importantly, this workbook was turned into a "shared" workbook only because I had started to use Track Changes, which turned on Workbook Sharing automatically when enabled.

This may or may not be the source of your problem, but perhaps it will help someone who comes across the same issue that I did. It's not clear to me why track changes / workbook sharing result in this behavior. (Could be a bug or a feature, though it sure seems like a UI bug when you no longer have access to components of your worksheet.)

Comment: Good job for a first time answer. You did a very good job of explaining how you had the same issue an was able to resolve it. This will be useful to many people.

Comment: A word of advice: especially while you are a new user and your reputation is low, try to get to the point more quickly. You spent three sentences elaborating the fact that you had a similar problem. Some people come here solely to say, "I had the same problem," and therefore some people will stop reading if, after three sentences, you haven't said that you actually have an answer. (Consider starting with "I solved a similar problem ....")

Answer (score 1):

For me, my problem was solved by turning on Design Mode under the Developer Tab.

Answer (score -2):

The solution is to click on the "Developer" menu -> Insert -> Select "Textbox" ActiveX control. Insert it somewhere (if you don't want to use it, then delete it), now you'll be able to select your textbox.